# ios splash screen

Tags: ios, splash-screen

I added default.png file for splah screen in iphone project. It works for every launch of the app. I want to set this splash screen only for the first run. And then when user clicks it will be hidden. For other runs I don't want to show it again. Is it possible with launch images feature or should i use a new view to do that?

Comment: I think you may be missing the point of Default.png. This image is there simply to provide a buffer between the springboard and your app. Having Default.png in place allows your to give the user a view of your main page before it loads so they aren't just looking at a black screen and waiting.

Answer (score 4):

You can't dynamically swap out "`Default.png`" between launches of your app.  That would break the code signing and your app wouldn't run or launch anymore.

Your best solution is to simply use a unique "`UIView`" after the splash (Default) screen disappears and display that "`UIView`" only on the first launch.

Comment: The closest he can do is black splash (black Default.png or absent file), and fade in his custom 'splash' afterwards, depending on first-launch, etc.

Comment: I am trying to create an image view programmatically for the first run now. Also I need a button to close it. Thanks.

Comment: Just create a "`UIViewController`", throw an image view and a button ("Understood", "Continue", "Close", etc.) into it and display *that* at first launch time.

Comment: Now I created a button dynamically for the first run. Button has a splash screen background. When user clicks, it becomes hidden. Which is the best way do you think?